# iOS: how to send the keyboard down after typing in textField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I want to send the keyboard down after writing in textField.

How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;` delegate method and tell the text field to resign it's first responder status.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: its not working.
can u tell me how to put the done button in keypad

Comment: You need to ensure that you set the delegate property of the text field to point to the instance of the class that you implemented the method in.
Also, you can set the `returnKeyType` on the textField to `UIReturnKeyTypeDone`

Answer (score 1):

**STEP-1:**

You need to set the delegate of the textField to File's Owner (using interface builder)

or

`textField.delegate = self;` from the viewController programmatically first

**STEP-2:**

And you implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender{ 
    [sender resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

connect this to didEndOnExit action of your textfield